# receive memory warning but consumer fewer

Tags: ios, memory-management

I'm doing a app like photo browser just like the "Photo" on iTOuch. And I use a third-party lib : https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser
When I scroll the photos several times, the app crashes.
The log shows that it has receive memory warning.

Then I use instrument to check the memory (I choose Memory-Allocation).

I track the Live Bytes and Overall Bytes for "All Allocations".
However, the Live Bytes is never more than 5 MB, and the Overall Bytes is beyond 100 MB .

When the app carshes, the Live Bytes is 3.97MB and the Overall is 125.48MB.

I think Live Bytes is the memory currently used, and it seems it costs a little.

Why the app still crashes?
Xcode 4.2 4D199,Lion 10.7.2(11c74), iTouch ios5.0.1 beta2.
Below is the screenshot, and the instrument configuration is the default.
[image]

Any idea?

the crash log is like:

```
Nov  8 16:54:42 unknown SpringBoard[15] : Received memory warning.
Nov  8 16:54:43 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] : (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0xcb31]) Exited: Killed: 9
Nov  8 16:54:43 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] : (UIKitApplication:com.freebit.minimumcloud.ios[0xf787]) Exited: Killed: 9
Nov  8 16:54:43 unknown UserEventAgent[12] : jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Nov  8 16:54:43 unknown SpringBoard[15] : Application 'Min.Cloud' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Nov  8 16:54:44 unknown SpringBoard[15] : Application 'FaceTime' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Nov  8 16:54:45 unknown kernel[0] : launchd[481] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Nov  8 16:54:45 unknown kernel[0] : launchd[481] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/301E2A00-F1B6-4E88-ACF4-8EBEFB92B9DA [69] (sandbox)
Nov  8 16:54:45 unknown librariand[459] : client connection is invalid: Connection invalid
Nov  8 16:54:45 unknown ReportCrash[480] : Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2011-11-08-165445.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
Nov  8 16:54:49 unknown sandboxd[483] : MinimumCloud(481) deny file-write-data /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/*********
Nov  8 16:54:50 unknown MinimumCloud[481] : file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/*******/Documents/
Nov  8 16:54:50 unknown sandboxd[483] : MinimumCloud(481) deny file-write-create /file:
Nov  8 16:54:50 unknown MinimumCloud[481] : ubiquityContainerURL=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/******/Documents
Nov  8 16:54:50 unknown sandboxd[483] : MinimumCloud(481) deny file-write-create /file:
Nov  8 16:54:50 unknown MinimumCloud[481] : mystorageSymLink=/var/mobile/Applications/301E2A00-F1B6-4E88-ACF4-8EBEFB92B9DA/Library/htdocs/MyStorage
Nov  8 16:54:51 unknown wifid[27] : WiFi:[342435291.518957]: Disable WoW requested by "spd"
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the crash log

Comment: you should provide all the relevant line for the crash but not the complete dump.

Comment: @UPT, I don't know where causes crash and hence where is the relevant line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my own fault!
when I use `NSURLConnection` to detect the `MIME-TYPE` of the file, the memory of the connection is never released and it becomes larger and larger(As I detect the type of more than 100 files).

I reconstruct the code.